# Call base method from non-derived code, is that possible? Legal?

Tags: c++

I'm perfectly aware of, that the syntax I'm about to show you, is the mechanism for calling e.g. a base-class method from within a derived class. But in some code I've come across, the same syntax is being used outside the class implementation, and I'm wondering if that is a legal (in the standard C++ sense) construct, and if the resulting behaviour is well defined?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void method(int arg)
    {
      ...
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void method(int arg)
    {
      ...
      Base::method(arg); // I'm fully comfortable with this...
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived d;
    Derived* pD = &d;
    pD->Base::method(2); // is this allowed?
    ...
```

Comment: Every time you think that something shouldn't be legal because it's "wrong" please remember that in most cases the C++ rule is "trust the programmer": if it's wrong the programmer won't do it. Please remember also that you can "memset" over an object instance if you're really pissed off :-D... if something cannot happen involuntarily there's no need to forbid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legal, yes, but it shows serious misdesign. A class (`Derived`, in this case) should offer a full interface, be it specific or inherited, and not force its callers to delve into its guts. If clients of `Derived` would reasonably need to call `Base::method` instead of `Derived::method`, then `Derived` should offer a public method to provide that functionality:

```
void alternateMethod(int arg) {Base::method(arg);}
```

Of course, if you really need to call `Base::method` and cannot change `Derived` (legacy code or an ill-designed external library), you may have no alternative but using that trick.

To summarise and answer your specific questions: yes, it is a legal construct, and yes, its behaviour is well defined. But redesigning `Derived` would be much better.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The design is one thing, but the ability to side-step the virtual-table of a class, was just not something I had seen before.